# How to disable Wpf combobox dropdown on hitting F4?

Tags: c#, wpf

I dont want F4 to open drop down of combobox.

I have tried to do it on keydown event of combobox. But even that event is not firing on F4

```
    void ComboBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.F4)
            this.IsDropDownOpen = false;
    }
```

Its not at all working please help in doing so.. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work. You may also try to handle the `PreviewKeyDown` event:

```
private void ComboBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.F4)
    {
        ((ComboBox)sender).IsDropDownOpen = false;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```